# Automate signing of a received document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We are trying to automate our testing. One step is that we get back a url to a docusign document, that needs a signature...without this, the 3rd party API (dev environment) won't proceed to the next step...but, we don't want a person involved, this is just a test environment, and we want the tests automated.

Is there a way to automate this signing in code? I'm looking at the c# client (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) but it appears that you can only open up envelopes and such that you create, not that were created by a different company (3rd party)

Are we going to have to abandon this test automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to automate the signing step via code. I have heard that Selenium is used by certain organizations to help automate the signing step for the sake of automated QA/regression testing.